# Jquery ajax populating a multi dimensional array feeding to a Google map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, multidimensional-array

I've a jquery ajax method which works well, it populates an array (points[]) of google maps latlngs which are then iterated through to plot them on the map. I also populate a second array (details[]) to get a link which I also use when generating the marker.

This is the Jquery a portion of the ajax code

```
 success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].long);
                points.push(latlng);            
                details.push(data[i].PageLink);                  
            }
            addMarkers();
        }
```

And then I create the marker by iterating through all items in the points array:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {

            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                map: map,
                position: points[i],
                icon: icon,
                url: details[i],
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(12, -5),
                labelClass: "labels"                    
            });
```

I'd like to make points[] into a multidimensional array so I can have the LAT/LNG in there as well as some more info like the link and maybe a title. Ideally I'd like all these to be put into this array but the syntax is not working for me.

I've tried variants of:

```
points[0].push(latlng);
points[1].push(data[i].PageLink);
```

But then when trying to assign these values to the marker I'm doing something wrong, presumably in my syntax, as I'm unable to get any values back from the array. Have I got this right in terms of how to populate the array and if so how do I then get that data back?

Comment: what about an object with lat, long, and other properties ?

Comment: Well, I think I need the latlng to be google.maps.LatLng objects because otherwise the method that clears the map points doesn't work. But, assuming this is wrong, how would I go about that?

Comment: THat works! Lovely, I've never really used Javascript objects before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  Raphaël Althaus who put me on to the idea of using a javascript object, I managed this by avoiding multidimensional arrays.

I created a new javascript object and assigned the various elements to it, it all worked perfectly.